# AJAX/JQUERY Can't seem to delete data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

Well my main problem is the button. I can't seem to find the reason why the button doesn't show up when I already clicked a certain tr

Here is the code that displays the returned employee data from the database

```
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
    $("#employee_list").append('<tr class="emp_delete" id="'+val.emp_id+'"><td>'+val.emp_id+'</td><td>'+val.last_name+'</td><td>'+val.first_name+
                                '</td><td>'+val.middle_in+'</td>'+
                                '<td><input type="button" value="Resigned Employee" class="deleteBtn" id="delete_"'+val.emp_id+'"></td></tr>');
                        });
```

and here is the code that shows the button if .emp_delete is clicked. then the .deleteBtn code to delete the certain data

```
$(".emp_delete").click(function(){
            var ID=$(this).attr('id');
            $("#delete_"+ID).show();        
        });

        $(".deleteBtn").click(function(){
            var ID=$(".emp_delete").attr('id');

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            var dataString = 'emp_id='+ID;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('c_employee/delete_employee'); ?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
```

**UPDATE**

The code that @Satpal gave worked but the .deleteBtn still doesn't show up after going through the each loop.

Here is the updated code:

```
$('#employee_list').delegate( ".emp_delete", 'click', function() {
              var ID=$(this).attr('id');

              $("#delete_"+ID).show();
        });


        $(".deleteBtn").click(function(){

            var ID=$(".emp_delete").attr('id');

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            var dataString = 'emp_id='+ID;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('c_employee/delete_employee'); ?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: 1. are you sure that event is binded and click function fired up upon buton clickung?

Answer (score 3):

**As you are adding HTML dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

In above example, `document` should be replaced with closest static container.

In Your case

```
$('#employee_list').on('click', ".emp_delete", function() {
      var ID=$(this).attr('id');
      $("#delete_"+ID).show();
});
```

Similarly you have to delegate event for `".deleteBtn"`

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

### EDIT

As per comment.

Since you are using jQuery 1.5, use [.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
 $(elements).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
```

In Your case

```
$('#employee_list').delegate( ".emp_delete", 'click', function() {
      var ID=$(this).attr('id');
      $("#delete_"+ID).show();
});
```

### EDIT 2

Use similar syntax for delete button also

```
$('#employee_list').delegate( ".deleteBtn", 'click', function() {
});
```

Comment: When I check my console, it displays

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @MelSyGallosa, Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js
I apologize. I'm still new with JQuery and Ajax.

Comment: the code works just fine but when the data generated with the each loop (the one above) it won't work anymore. I have no idea waz goin on -_-

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47448/discussion-between-mel-sy-gallosa-and-satpal)

Comment: i updated my post above sir. Please checkout my prob :(

Comment: @MelSyGallosa, Use `$('#employee_list').delegate( ".deleteBtn", 'click', function() {` in place of `$(".deleteBtn").click(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

You mean the button does not fire?

If so, that is because you define the function before you insert the element in the DOM, you need to bind it.

So instead of:

```
$(".deleteBtn").click(function(){
```

Put:

```
$("#employee_list").on("click",".deleteBtn",function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the document has been fully loaded, each time you add a new object to the DOM dynamically (like adding a new table row with buttons) you'll need to bind the generated element to an event or action, you cannot say "do something when someone clicks any button" you'd say "do something when someone clicks THIS button" meaning that you have to have the object created first in order to "attach" some action to it.

So let's say that you have these:

```
<button class="action-button" id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="action-button" id="2">Button 2</button>
```

And then this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".action-button").click(function(){
        alert('My id is ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

And then you later decide to add a button with some action on your js/html:

```
<button class="action-button" id="3">Button 3</button>
```

Surprise! If you click button 3 you'll get no alert...? Why, because the function that you set up for click event on document.ready parsed only the initial two buttons that existed at that moment, but since you added a third one dynamically later, the document.ready code wasn't aware of it.

So as Emil pointed out, each time you create a new element you'll want to bind it, in our example, for our button 3:

```
$('#3').bind('click', function(){
    alert('My id is ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Or by the class, which is not adequate cause it would rebind existing elements and you lose performance:

```
$('.action-button').bind('click', function(){
    alert('My id is ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

So make sure that if you add elements that do actions or call functions you bind them when you add them, ideally, have a separate function which does whatever the button needs to do and then when you bind the new element, bind it to that function instead of putting a direct callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery version less than 1.9:

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){

});
```

Comment: live is deprecated - don't teach somebody to use methods which are not supported, they will learn the wrong way.

Comment: @Emil i just mention above!!
I'm not teaching just to aware if he ever get this code somewhere

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with the id delete

```
<div id="di"></div>
<a href="#" id="algo">Algo</a>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#algo').click(function(){
    var a = 1;
    //THIS IS IMPORTANT , SEE ID = "delete_" <- has a problem
    $('#di').html('<td><input type="button" value="Resigned Employee" class="deleteBtn" id="delete_'+a+'"></td></tr>');

});
</script>
```

Is id="delete_'+val.emp_id+'" and not id="delete_"'+val.emp_id+'" (" <- error)

Comment: it is not an error. I have to put a double quote after delete_ then a single quote